# Docker Compose with .net and mysql "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, docker, yaml

When I run the project I got the error:

```
'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'
```

[image]

Both Containers are running but the connection is not established between API project and Mysql.
Here yaml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: lc_dbt
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
    volumes:
       - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
       - ./_MySQL_Init_Script:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always

  lc_erp:
    depends_on:
       - db
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}lcerp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: LC_ERP/Dockerfile
```

Here is my Connection String:

```
"Release": "server=localhost; userid=root;pwd=12345;port=3306;database=lc_dbt"
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong in yaml file? Thank you.

Comment: The host name of the db-host should be the container-name of the db-container (i.e. `db`). Otherwise the `lc_erp`-container tries to itself (`localhost`) on port 3306, where nothing is running.